# Vuejs : how to update data in child component?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm beginning in vuejs, and I try to create a button menu component, with sub-menu, sub-sub-menu and so on.

When I click on button, the sub-button is displayed, or hidden if already displayed. On sub-button, the behaviour is the same. My problems is when I click on button when the sub-sub-button is displayed : the sub-button is hidden as expected. Next, I click anew, the sub-button is displayed, but the sub-sub-button also !

Here a little schema :

```
Menu -> Menu    -> Menu    -> Menu -> Menu
        Submenu    Submenu            Submenu
                   SubSubMenu         Subsubmenu
```

But I would :

```
Menu -> Menu    -> Menu    -> Menu -> Menu
        Submenu    Submenu            Submenu
                   SubSubMenu
```

Here the code :

```
<template>
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-text mr-2">
        <a
            class="nav-link"
            v-bind:class="{withChildren: menu.children && menu.children.length }"
            v-on:click="switchDisplayChildren"
            href="#"
        >{{ menu.text }}</a>
        <ul 
            v-if="menu.children && menu.children.length"
            v-bind:class="{'dropdown-menu-hide': !displayChildren, 'dropdown-menu-show': displayChildren }"
        >
            <navbar-button v-for="child in menu.children" :key="child.id" :menu="child"></navbar-button>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "NavbarButton",
        props: ["menu"],
        data: function() {
            return {
                displayChildren: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            switchDisplayChildren: function() {
                this.displayChildren = !this.displayChildren;
                this.hideChildren();
            },
            hideChildren: function() {
                if (!this.displayChildren && this.menu.children) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.menu.children.length; i++) {
                        var child = this.menu.children[i];
                        child.displayChildren = false;
                        child.hideChildren();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The variable `displayChildren` switch between true and false, updating the class from `dropdown-menu-hide` to `dropdown-menu-show` and vice-versa. But I get the message :

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: child.hideChildren is not a function"

What do I wrong in my code ? And, is my idea to use variable `displayChildren` correct ?

I use Vuejs in version 2.6.10.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found how do I want. I pass props as object :

```
<template>
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-text mr-2">
        <a
            class="nav-link"
            v-bind:class="{withChildren: children && children.length }"
            v-on:click="switchDisplayChildren"
            href="#"
        >{{ text }}</a>
        <ul 
            v-if="children && children.length"
            v-bind:class="{'dropdown-menu-hide': !displayChildren, 'dropdown-menu-show': displayChildren }"
        >
            <navbar-button v-for="child in children" :key="child.id" v-bind="child"></navbar-button>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "NavbarButton",
        props: {
            id: Number,
            text: String,
            displayChildren: Boolean,
            children: Array
        },
        methods: {
            switchDisplayChildren: function() {
                this.displayChildren = !this.displayChildren;
                if (!this.displayChildren) {
                    this.hideChildren(this.children);
                }
            },
            hideChildren: function(children) {
                if (children) {
                    var count = children.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                        var child = children[i];
                        child.displayChildren = false;
                        this.hideChildren(child.children);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```